# A Bidirectional scroll view for Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need a bidirectional scroll view with pinch and zoom gesture added to it. Is it recommended to have a scroll view with horizontal scroll view as its child view or a custom implementation is the only solution?

Answer (score 7):

Yan. Yurkin answered a similar question. You don't need a custom view but you have to handle the touch events. This soulution by Yan is for a verticalscrollview inside of a horizontal one:

> There is much more simpler solution than creating a custom view:

Layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/scrollHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollVertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <WateverViewYouWant/>

    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Code (onCreate/onCreateView):

```
final HorizontalScrollView hScroll = (HorizontalScrollView) value.findViewById(R.id.scrollHorizontal);
final ScrollView vScroll = (ScrollView) value.findViewById(R.id.scrollVertical);
vScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { //inner scroll listener         
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
});
hScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { //outer scroll listener         
    private float mx, my, curX, curY;
    private boolean started = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        curX = event.getX();
        curY = event.getY();
        int dx = (int) (mx - curX);
        int dy = (int) (my - curY);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (started) {
                    vScroll.scrollBy(0, dy);
                    hScroll.scrollBy(dx, 0);
                } else {
                    started = true;
                }
                mx = curX;
                my = curY;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                vScroll.scrollBy(0, dy);
                hScroll.scrollBy(dx, 0);
                started = false;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

>

Comment: Its is too glitchy